# F# Bug with named regular expressions?

Tags: regex, f#

I was trying to get a named regular expression working in F# without much luck. Ported to C# and it works. Is there some peculiarity with F# that I'm missing here or is it a bug?

F#

```ml
open System.Text.RegularExpressions;;
let regex = new Regex("(?<liveId>WindowsLiveID)|(?<facebook>Facebook)", RegexOptions.Compiled ||| RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);;
let m = regex.Matches("ImWindowsLiveIDOK");;
m.[0].Groups.["liveID"].Success;;
```

C#

```cs
var regex = new Regex("(?<liveId>WindowsLiveID)|(?<facebook>Facebook)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Matches("ImWindowsLiveIDOK");
Console.WriteLine(match[0].Groups["liveId"].Success);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groups are case sensitive. You have `"liveID"` on F#, and `"liveId"` on C# (note the `D`).
On the first block, there is no group called `liveID`, so it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You have a spelling mistake in your group name: try "liveId" instead of "liveID"